# Correct way of rewriting `forms.ChoiceField` into a ModelField? Is it models.ForeignKey?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-forms

I am converting a survey from a `Form` to a `ModelForm` in Django 1.6.2 but I am having an issue selecting the right field type for `ChoiceField`. The survey was implemented using a SessionWizardView.

My question is: What is the correct way of rewriting the below code which used to be in my forms.py into my models.py using ModelForm?

## The old code:

**forms.py**

```
class SurveyFormA(forms.Form):

    MALE = 'M'
    FEMALE = 'F'
           
    SEX = (
        ("", "----------"), 
        (MALE, "Male"),
        (FEMALE, "Female"),
               )   
    sex = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(), choices=SEX, initial= "", label='What sex are you?', required = False)
```

The below is my attempt but from reading the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.ModelForm) which lists corresponding Form fields for every Model field except `ChoiceField`, I am not 100% certain that I am correct.

## The new code:

**forms.py**

```
class SurveyFormA(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ['sex']
```

**models.py**

```
class Person(models.Model):
                            
    MALE = 'M'
    FEMALE = 'F'
    
    SEX = (
        (MALE, "Male"),
        (FEMALE, "Female"))   
    
    sex = models.ForeignKey('Person', related_name='Person_sex', null=True, choices=SEX, verbose_name='What sex are you?')
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not correct. Take a look at [Django's `choices` documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#choices).

Replace your line

```
sex = models.ForeignKey('Person', related_name='Person_sex',
                        null=True, choices=SEX, verbose_name='What sex are you?')
```

with

```
sex = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SEX,
                       verbose_name='What sex are you?', null=True)
```

The value stored in your database will be "F" or "M", but Django will display "Female" or "Male" in your `ModelForm`. There's a nice explanation about this [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display).